# How to add new keyboard layouts in kivy?

Tags: json, keyboard, kivy

I am developing a little dictionary app in Kivy.  Clearly, it would be very useful, mandatory even, to have different keyboard layouts depending on the languages I want to cover with my dictionary.

There are a few layouts in: kivy27\kivy\data\keyboards, but that is hardly enough for my needs.

Does anyone know where can additional keyboard layouts in .json format be found?  I really don't think it is necessary to reinvent the wheel here.

If not, is there a software which allows for an easier editing of .json files?  Editing them by hand seems a tedious and error-prone process :-(

Comment: You could ask on the kivy-users mailing list or irc where these layouts originally came from - they probably weren't typed in by hand, at least not at the kivy stage.

Comment: OK, thanks, will do that.